# Unable to connect to Internet from inside docker container even after using --network=host

Tags: docker

I am using a Windows 10 machine, in a corporate network and we have a proxy server that is required in order to access the internet. I have set the same proxy in the docker desktop settings.

However, once I create a container, I am not able to connect to the internet from inside the container.

I used the command `docker container run -it --network=host -v /d/path/to/local/folder:/app ubuntu` to create a ubuntu container in docker. It ran successfully, and I was able to enter the container. Once inside the container, I tried to do an apt-get update, so that I can go ahead and install other packages, but, I got the following error, which looks like it means, I am not able to access the internet from inside the container.

```
root@docker-desktop:/# apt-get update
Err:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
  Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1560:8001::14). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1360:8001::21). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1560:8001::11). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1360:8001::17). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.88.162). - connect (111: Connection refused) Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.88.31). - connect (111: Connection refused) Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.88.149). - connect (111: Connection refused) Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.88.24). - connect (111: Connection refused) Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.88.173). - connect (111: Connection refused) Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.88.174). - connect (111: Connection refused)
Err:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease
  Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1560:8001::14). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1360:8001::21). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1560:8001::11). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1360:8001::17). - connect (101: Network is unreachable)
.
.
.
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: do you have a proxy configured?

Comment: I have it configured in the docker desktop application

Comment: Make sure archive.ubuntu.com can be resolved inside the docker (use ping to test)
Use `curl archive.ubuntu.com:80` to test if the docker can access the proxy